# why mapping over array of objects doesn't work in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, array.prototype.map

P.S: I added an edited version of the code down below.

I have some JSON data that I extract from it the doctor's value and update the state with then  I want to map on it and print out the values.
now it has only one doctor but later it can have more than one doctor that's why I want to map on it and print the values in fragment.

in the console .log I get this error

```
c-sessionfrag.js:50 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id')
    at handleloop (c-sessionfrag.js:50:1)
```

this is the JSON data

```
{
    "totalReservations": 1,
    "allReservations": [
        {
            "_id": "62d5f88672dd3fadbeeee7d5",
            "userId": {
                "_id": "62cf836dbbb2ddfdcca4df4d",
                "image": "https://res.cloudinary.com/devsalem/image/upload/v1657766765/YOU/fuiiwkvdxwgczpfkv4d9.jpg",
                "name": "Hassan Ibrahim",
                "mobilePhone": "01010644258",
                "gender": "male",
                "email": "nohahassan497@yahoo.com",
                "birthDate": "1991-06-04",
                "trustContact": "01016166161",
                "contactRelation": "mom",
                "sessions": [
                    "Individual Session"
                ]
            },
            "doctor": {
                "_id": "62cf8f75bb6b1eb825e8ab93",
                "image": "https://res.cloudinary.com/devsalem/image/upload/v1657769832/YOU/umf1hkh7mjtasd5zy0vr.jpg",
                "name": "ruba hamed",
                "mobilePhone": "01222990000",
                "gender": "female",
                "email": "drruba1111@gmail.com",
                "birthDate": "22/4/1980",
                "languages": [
                    "english, spanish, arabic"
                ],
                "licIssuedDate": "22/2/1998",
                "licExpiryDate": "22/2/1999",
                "profession": "therapist",
                "sessionPrice": "400"
            },
            "startDate": "12:00 pm",
            "date": "2022-07-26",
            "roomName": "6feb87ad-b0cb-4877-a5ed-44e0c1f79fd8"
        }
    ]
}
```

but for some reason, it does not print anything.
here is the array of data

```
0: {_id: '62cf8f75bb6b1eb825e8ab93', image: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/devsalem/image/upload/v1657769832/YOU/umf1hkh7mjtasd5zy0vr.jpg', name: 'ruba hamed', mobilePhone: '01222990000', gender: 'female', …}
1: {_id: '62cf8f75bb6b1eb825e8ab93', image: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/devsalem/image/upload/v1657769832/YOU/umf1hkh7mjtasd5zy0vr.jpg', name: 'ruba hamed', mobilePhone: '01222990000', gender: 'female', …}
2: {_id: '62cf8f75bb6b1eb825e8ab93', image: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/devsalem/image/upload/v1657769832/YOU/umf1hkh7mjtasd5zy0vr.jpg', name: 'ruba hamed', mobilePhone: '01222990000', gender: 'female', …}
3: {_id: '62cf8f75bb6b1eb825e8ab93', image: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/devsalem/image/upload/v1657769832/YOU/umf1hkh7mjtasd5zy0vr.jpg', name: 'ruba hamed', mobilePhone: '01222990000', gender: 'female', …}
length: 4
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

here is my code

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

import axios from "axios";

import './c-session.css';

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faPhone, faCalendar } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

import clientimg from '../../../pictures/0_GettyImages-1333254883.png';
import clientname from '../../../pictures/icons8-name-tag-48.png';
import clientdate from '../../../pictures/Icon material-date-range.png';
import clientsession from '../../../pictures/icons8-question-and-answer-session-with-speech-bubble-48.png';
import clientcall from '../../../pictures/icons8-video-call-64.png';

const CSessionFrag = (props) => {

    console.log('hi noha ana l frag');
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const token = props.token;

    const [date, setDate] = useState();
    const doctors = { doctor: [], user: [], startDate: "", date: "", roomName: "", sessionID: "" };

    const [doctorsArray, setDoctorsArray] = useState(doctors);
    const [doctorsNoha, setDoctorsNoha] = useState([]);

    async function noha() {
        await setDoctorsNoha([...doctorsNoha, doctorsArray.doctor]);

    }

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('/reservation', {
            headers: {
                'token': token
            }
        })
            .then(res => {
                console.log('sesssssssssssion fragment of doctorProfile response', res.data.allReservations[0].doctor);
                console.log('sesssssssssssion fragment of doctorProfile response', res.data.allReservations[0].roomName);
                setDate(res.data.allReservations[0].date)
                const reserv = res.data.allReservations;
                async function handleloop(reserv) {
                    for (var i = 0; i <= reserv.length; i++) {
                        await setDoctorsArray({
                            sessionID: reserv[i]._id,
                            startDate: reserv[i].startDate,
                            date: reserv[i].date,
                            doctor: reserv[i].doctor,
                            user: reserv[i].userId,
                            roomName: reserv[i].roomName
                        });
                    }
                    console.log('done loop');
                }
                handleloop(reserv);

                noha();
                // const allData = reserv[0].doctor;
                // setImmediate(res.data.allReservations.date);
            }).catch(e => {
                console.log('sesion errooooooor', e);
            })

    }, []);



    console.log('l arayyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy', doctorsArray.doctor);
    console.log('l doctorrrrrrrrrr', doctorsNoha);


    return (
        <Fragment>
            {
                doctorsNoha.map(doctor => {
                    <Fragment key={doctor._id} >
                        <div className="c-session_card">

                            <div className="c-session_card_top">
                                <img className="c-session_card_top_img" src={doctor.image} />
                            </div>
                            <div className="c-session_card_middle">
                                <p className="c-session_card_txt" id="c-session_card_name">
                                    <img className="c-session_card_icon" id="c-session_name" src={clientname} />
                                    {doctor.name}
                                </p>

                                <p className="c-session_card_txt" >
                                    <img className="c-session_card_icon" src={clientcall} />
                                    {doctor.profession}
                                </p>
                                <p className="c-session_card_txt" id="c-session_date_p" >
                                    <img className="c-session_card_icon" id="c-session_date" src={clientdate} />
                                    {date}
                                </p>
                                <p className="c-session_card_txt" id="c-session_date_p" >
                                    <img className="c-session_card_icon" id="c-session_date" src={clientdate} />
                                    {doctor.sessionPrice}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="c-session_card_bottom">
                                <button className="c-session_card_bottom_btn" id="c-session_profile_btn" onClick={() => { navigate('/doctorprofile', { state: { docId: doctor._id } }) }}>Profile</button>
                                <button className="c-session_card_bottom_btn" id="c-session_call_btn" onClick={() => navigate('/startsession', { state: { docId: doctor._id } })}>
                                    <FontAwesomeIcon
                                        icon={faPhone}
                                        id="c-session_call_btn_icon"
                                    />
                                    Start Session
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Fragment >

                })}
        </Fragment >
    );
}

export default CSessionFrag;
```

here is the edited code, it works without error but the doctorsNoha state is not updating, and on page load it creates an empty array

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

import axios from "axios";

import './c-session.css';

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faPhone, faCalendar } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

import clientimg from '../../../pictures/0_GettyImages-1333254883.png';
import clientname from '../../../pictures/icons8-name-tag-48.png';
import clientdate from '../../../pictures/Icon material-date-range.png';
import clientsession from '../../../pictures/icons8-question-and-answer-session-with-speech-bubble-48.png';
import clientcall from '../../../pictures/icons8-video-call-64.png';

const CSessionFrag = (props) => {

    console.log('hi noha ana l frag');
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const token = props.token;

    const [date, setDate] = useState();
    const doctors = { doctor: [], user: [], startDate: "", date: "", roomName: "", sessionID: "" };

    const [doctorsArray, setDoctorsArray] = useState(doctors);
    const [doctorsNoha, setDoctorsNoha] = useState([]);

    async function nohawait(doctorsArray) {
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('/reservation', {
            headers: {
                'token': token
            }
        })
            .then(res => {
                console.log('sesssssssssssion fragment of doctorProfile response', res.data.allReservations[0].doctor);
                console.log('sesssssssssssion fragment of doctorProfile response', res.data.allReservations[0].roomName);
                setDate(res.data.allReservations[0].date)
                const reserv = res.data.allReservations;
                async function handleloop(reserv) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < reserv.length; i++) {
                        await setDoctorsArray({
                            sessionID: reserv[i]._id,
                            startDate: reserv[i].startDate,
                            date: reserv[i].date,
                            doctor: reserv[i].doctor,
                            user: reserv[i].userId,
                            roomName: reserv[i].roomName
                        });
                        setDoctorsNoha(current => [...current, doctorsArray.doctor]);

                    }

                    console.log('done loop');

                }
                handleloop(reserv);


                // const allData = reserv[0].doctor;
                // setImmediate(res.data.allReservations.date);
            }).catch(e => {
                console.log('sesion errooooooor', e);
            })
    }, []);



    console.log('l arayyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy', doctorsArray.doctor);
    console.log('l doctorrrrrrrrrr', doctorsNoha);
    console.log('rommmmmnme', doctorsArray.roomName);

    return (
        <Fragment>
            {
                doctorsNoha.map(doctor =>
                    <Fragment key={doctor._id} >
                        <div className="c-session_card">

                            <div className="c-session_card_top">
                                <img className="c-session_card_top_img" src={doctor.image} />
                            </div>
                            <div className="c-session_card_middle">
                                <p className="c-session_card_txt" id="c-session_card_name">
                                    <img className="c-session_card_icon" id="c-session_name" src={clientname} />
                                    {doctor.name}
                                </p>

                                <p className="c-session_card_txt" >
                                    <img className="c-session_card_icon" src={clientcall} />
                                    {doctor.profession}
                                </p>
                                <p className="c-session_card_txt" id="c-session_date_p" >
                                    <img className="c-session_card_icon" id="c-session_date" src={clientdate} />
                                    {date}
                                </p>
                                <p className="c-session_card_txt" id="c-session_date_p" >
                                    <img className="c-session_card_icon" id="c-session_date" src={clientdate} />
                                    {doctor.sessionPrice}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="c-session_card_bottom">
                                <button className="c-session_card_bottom_btn" id="c-session_profile_btn" onClick={() => { navigate('/doctorprofile', { state: { docId: doctor._id } }) }}>Profile</button>
                                <button className="c-session_card_bottom_btn" id="c-session_call_btn" onClick={() => navigate('/startsession', { state: { docId: doctor._id, roomName: doctorsArray.roomName } })}>
                                    <FontAwesomeIcon
                                        icon={faPhone}
                                        id="c-session_call_btn_icon"
                                    />
                                    Start Session
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Fragment >

                )}
        </Fragment >
    );
}

export default CSessionFrag;
```

Comment: If a employer see your long console.logs,  he wont be happy with your code... try to organize your code base , things will be more easer to read and debug !!

Comment: Which line throws the error?  This one?: `<Fragment key={doctor._id} >`  If so then `doctorsNoha` contains at least one element that is `undefined`.  Or is it another line that throws the error?  Can you either provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem or provide some more specific debugging information about the state of the array you're mapping over when the error occurs?

Comment: @stop-error I am a still student and these long console.logs are just for me to easily notice them in the console. I will delete them later

Comment: @David I have solved the error by maintaining the for loop to be < not <=. but still no data shows on the screen

Comment: I didn't mean it in a bad way.... it is a bad habit that will stick ! if you know what I mean I am talking from an experience to make your life easier for later :)

Comment: @Noha: At a glance, the function used inside the call to `.map()` doesn't return anything.  Either use the `return` keyword or remove the curly braces.  Arrow functions only have implicit returns when there are no curly braces.

Comment: @David it worked, thank you. Can i ask you another question! the State of doctorsNohaArray every time I run the code it creates an empty array inside of it. hwo can I set in a way that does not create this empty array

Comment: @stop-error it is okay, I am open to learning form the experts

Answer (score 0):

When you start iterating from `0` you have to stop iterating before the length of the array

Swap this:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= reserv.length; i++) {
```

With this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < reserv.length; i++) {
```

You are getting an error, because `reserv[1]` is `undefined`.

Comment: this helped me solve the error but still no data showed on the screen     @konrad

Comment: When `noha` fired `doctorsArray` isn't populated yet, because React doesn't update the state instantly. You have to pass this data to `noha` as an argument or use `useEffect` to update it.

Comment: i edited my setDoctorsNoha to be  setDoctorsNoha(current => [...current, doctorsArray.doctor] and put line inside the useEffect. put still it is not updated @Konrad

Comment: Did you added `doctorsArray` as a dependency?

Comment: yes i did it and put is at the end of useEffect .........async function nohawait(doctorsArray) {
            await setDoctorsNoha(current => [...current, doctorsArray.doctor]);
        }
        nohawait(doctorsArray);

Comment: `async` and `await` don't do anything as state setters doesn't return a promise

Comment: i see, i will remove it.